# celery stuck at mingle: searching for neighbors, doesn't get to ready state

Tags: python, celery

I had run celery for my project using 10 threads. It worked perfectly.
Now, when i use the command:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info --concurrency 10
```

celery get stuck at :

```
[2014-08-07 12:55:21,013: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2014-08-07 12:55:21,025: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
```

earlier it showed **ready** state after this.

and when i try to end this using **ctrl+c**, it doesn't shutdown.

```
[2014-08-07 12:55:21,013: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to     amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2014-08-07 12:55:21,025: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
^C
worker: Hitting Ctrl+C again will terminate all running tasks!

worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)
^C
worker: Cold shutdown (MainProcess)
^C
worker: Cold shutdown (MainProcess)
^C
worker: Cold shutdown (MainProcess)
^C
worker: Cold shutdown (MainProcess)
^C
worker: Cold shutdown (MainProcess)
^C
worker: Cold shutdown (MainProcess)
```

I even tried to assign task to the workers, but it doesn't work.

I want to celery to be at ready state? can anybody help?

Also I need a proper way to end celery process, including tasks,queues annd workers.
thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your free disk space. RabbitMQ requires 1Gb of free space by default.

Comment: The best thing is that rabbit does not say anything in his startup_err or startup_log ... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For further information, the RabbitMQ requires 1Gb if in standalone. If you are running a RabbitMQ cluster **all** nodes of the cluster should have 1Gb free disk space.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was because the RabbitMQ message broker crashed, restarting it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Database backend, adding the following options to `celery` should solve the problem: `--without-gossip --without-mingle`.

See [the related issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1664) on github.