# celeryd with RabbitMQ hangs on "mingle: searching for neighbors", but plain celery works

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, celeryd

I'm banging my head to the wall with celeryd and RabbitMQ.

This example from tutorial is working just fine:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
return x + y
```

I run:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

And I get the output:

```
[2014-11-18 19:47:58,874: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2014-11-18 19:47:58,881: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2014-11-18 19:47:59,889: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2014-11-18 19:47:59,896: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 ready.
```

I can run the task now from python repl and get a result.

But when I install celeryd, the process hangs up on the mingle-step:

```
[2014-11-18 20:18:33,893: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
```

No output after this appears.

My /etc/default/celeryd looks like this:

```
ENABLED="true"
CELERYD_NODES="w1"
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/myusername/src/celery-test"
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"
CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="celeryconfig"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
```

I'm using these versions:

Ubuntu 14.04
celery 3.1.16 (Cipater)
celeryd 3.1.6-1ubuntu1
rabbitmq-server 3.2.4-1
Python 2.7.6

So without daemonizing, celery can initialize itself, but with daemon (celeryd) hangs on the mingle-step apparently.

Some forums suggest that this is a problem with RabbitMQ reaching a disk space limit. I have plenty of disk, and RabbitMQ's own logs do not indicate any problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Database backend, adding the following options to celery should solve the problem:

```
    --without-mingle
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a hunch from this message:

```
[2014-11-18 16:20:17,216: WARNING/MainProcess] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/librabbitmq.py:163: UserWarning:
    librabbitmq version too old to detect RabbitMQ version information
    so make sure you are using librabbitmq 1.5 when using rabbitmq > 3.3

  warnings.warn(UserWarning(W_VERSION))
```

So for some reason I had librabbitmq1 apt package and it was too old.

And it turns out that problem was librabbitmq1 package. I removed it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove librabbitmq1
```

And the python Celery/RabbitMQ libs did some kind of fallback to some other (maybe plain-python?) implementation which works!

Answer (score -1):

Check your free disk space. RabbitMQ requires 1Gb of free space by default.

Comment: I stated in my question: "I have plenty of disk, and RabbitMQ's own logs do not indicate any problem."

Comment: Try to restart your rabbitmq server or  use --without-mingle --without-gossip in circus conf file.  i just reinstall rabbitmq and it worked for me :)